# How do I extend a jquery functions to several elements without duplicating all the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.print_no_1').bind('click',function() {
        var thePopup = window.open( '', "Print widnow", "menubar=0,location=0,height=700,width=700" );
        $('#print_img_1').clone().appendTo( thePopup.document.body );
        thePopup.print();
    });
});
```

Which I'm using to trigger the print of an image when a link is clicked

```
<img style="" id="print_img_1" src="<?php echo $day_event_print[0]; ?>" title="" alt="" />
<a href="#" class="print_no_1" />click here</a>
```

What I would like to know is what is the best way to apply the same function to three other images avoiding to duplicate the hole jquery code three times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    (function (n) {
        $('.print_no_' + n).bind('click',function() {
            var thePopup = window.open( '', "Print widnow", "menubar=0,location=0,height=700,width=700" );
            $('#print_img_' + n).clone().appendTo( thePopup.document.body );
            thePopup.print();
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! got it and to the elements I just add numbers at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div class="myContainer">
<img style="myImage" src="<?php echo $day_event_print[0]; ?>" title="" alt="" />
<a href="#" class="myLink" />click here</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myLink').bind('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var thePopup = window.open( '', "Print widnow", "menubar=0,location=0,height=700,width=700" );
        $(this).parent().find('.myImage')[0].clone().appendTo( thePopup.document.body );
        thePopup.print();
    });
});
```

With this, aways a html class "myLink" is clicked, javascript will get it parent and search for the image and then do the same behavior with all. I think is that what you need.